# Passing string to ant script

Tags: shell, ant

I want to pass the below string as input to shell script :

```
ant -f build.xml run -class_name="new_class" -arguments ="-n name -w default -print -o $1.txt"
```

I wrote a shell script as below:

```
#!/bin/bash
"$1"
```

input : `text.sh " ant -f build.xml run -class_name="new_class" -arguments ="-n name -w default -print -o $1.txt"`

Output:

> ant command not found

I also included the environmental variables to the shell script . 
But my ant script is not input to my shell script .

Comment: saranyaa, but are you considering multiple strings as one arguments to the shell script? Can give little more context by editing the question on what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What is the command result of `which ant`? `echo $CLASSPATH`

Comment: Hi Rao . I have included the local file to read my environment variable .

Comment: As an answer to your first question , since ant has sapces , ' and "" involved i guess i should pass it as a string

Answer (score 0):

First, if you *really* invoke your script in the exact way you are posted, you should get an error message saying * ant -f build.xml .....* not found.

Second, your quoting on the calling side is, while not invalid, odd. You have a quoted string `ant -f build.xml run -class_name=`, which is followed immediately by an unquoted string `new_class`. What's the purpose of this?

If you want the script to execute a string exactly as given, you could simply do a

```
$1
```

instead of `"$1"`, and call it as

```
text.sh "ant -f build.xml run -class_name=new_class -arguments ='-n name -w default -print -o $1.txt'"
```

Note the use of quoting in the call.

Comment: Hi , can u please tell me how to just pass an ant script as an input to shell script . I'm confused how , as the ant script has spaces and "" in it .

Comment: simply when i pass my ant script as input to  ./text.sh  , im getting an error "no such file or directory "

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. I don't think that you really want to pass an ant **script** (i.e. the XML text) to a shell script, but:  Do you want to pass just the filename of the ant script to a shell script, or do you want to pass a complete `ant` command (including parameters) to a shell script? In the latter case, you have to be careful with quoting (or use Zsh instead of bash, which has more programmer-friendly quoting rules).